# Java Concurrency in Practice “Listing 7.21. ExecutorService that keeps track of cancelled tasks after shutdown.”. Where is the race condition?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading *Java Concurrency in Practice* and encounter the following code snippet.

```
public class TrackingExecutor extends AbstractExecutorService {
    private final ExecutorService exec;
    private final Set<Runnable> tasksCancelledAtShutdown =
            Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Runnable>());
    ...
    public List<Runnable> getCancelledTasks() {
        if (!exec.isTerminated())
            throw new IllegalStateException(...);
        return new ArrayList<Runnable>(tasksCancelledAtShutdown);
    }

    public void execute(final Runnable runnable) {
        exec.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } finally {
                    if (isShutdown()
                            && Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                        tasksCancelledAtShutdown.add(runnable);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // delegate other ExecutorService methods to exec
}
```

The book says:

> TrackingExecutor has an unavoidable race condition that could make it yield false positives: tasks that are identified as cancelled but actually completed. This arises because the thread pool could be shut down between when the last instruction of the task executes and when the pool records the task as complete.

Does it mean the below situation?

1. one worker thread has finished `runnable.run()`, but stop at `finally` block.
2. `exec` is shut down.
3. the worker thread executes `finally` block and add `runnable` into `tasksCancelledAtShutdown`. (`runnable.run()` has been finished, **it should be recognized as `finished`, not `cancelledAtShutdown`.**)

Do I get it right? If not, where is the race condition? What does "the thread pool could be shut down between when the last instruction of the task executes and when the pool records the task as complete" really mean?

Comment: Yes. (padding).

Comment: "the thread pool could be shut down between when the last instruction of the task executes and when the pool records the task as complete" really makes me confused.

Comment: Consider this interleaving of statements: Thread 1: `runnable.run();`. Thread 2: `exec.shutdown();`. T1: `if (isShutdown())` ... The executor wasn't shutdown when `runnable.run()` completed, but was when it checked if the ES was shut down.

Comment: I know, this is what I say in the question body.

Comment: OK, then you're going to need to be a bit more precise about the nature of your confusion.

Comment: OK, these two things make me confused. 1. last instruction of the task executes 2. the pool records the task as complete

Comment: What about those make you confused? (I'm not trying to be obtuse, I'm genuinely not understanding what is confusing about those two things: they're simply two different places in the sequence of commands executed by that thread. I think "the pool records the tasks as complete" is a bit imprecise, since I think that's actually referring to [everything in the finally block]).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205281/discussion-between-jason-law-and-andy-turner).

Comment: How about in the runnable, the final line will clear the interrupted status of the thread, then it should not have this problem anymore.